# How Do i Get This Discord Bot Created By discord bot maker to work on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, discord, discord.js

so the bot works perfectly when running it localy but when i run it on heroku it gives me a error saying:

```
2018-08-29T13:57:58.295022+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: 
The http2 module is an experimental API.
2018-08-29T13:57:58.732365+00:00 app[web.1]: Bot is ready!
2018-08-29T13:58:55.278962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> 
Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-08-29T13:58:55.278962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with 
SIGKILL
2018-08-29T13:58:55.404294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-08-29T13:58:55.623262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

now if i try there soultion:

```
2018-08-29T14:07:46.618465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `node bot.js`
2018-08-29T14:07:48.107034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063674+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bot.js:8
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063700+00:00 app[web.1]: app.listen(PORT, () => {
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063701+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063703+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063704+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: app is not defined
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063706+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/app/bot.js:8:1)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063707+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile 
(module.js:652:30)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063709+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063711+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load 
(module.js:565:32)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad 
(module.js:505:12)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063714+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(module.js:497:3)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063716+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain 
(module.js:693:10)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063718+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup 
(bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-08-29T14:07:48.063720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-08-29T14:07:48.120800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
```

also the script that i added:https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...it seems that the error is that `app` is not defined.

I am assuming you are using the JS Express library, so make sure the Express library was correctly installed. Double check if you are importing it correctly into your program, and make sure to define
`const app = express();`